# Children of Many Parents jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-selectors, iterator

I am trying to select every first child of any parent with the class `.Payment`

Sample HTML :

```
<div class='payment'>
  <input id="payments_0_:date_paid" name="payments[0][:date_paid]" type="text" />
  <br>
  <input id="payments_0_:amount_paid" name="payments[0][:amount_paid]" type="text" />
</div>
<div class='payment'>
  <input id="payments_1_:date_paid" name="payments[0][:date_paid]" type="text" />
  <br>
  <input id="payments_1_:amount_paid" name="payments[0][:amount_paid]" type="text" />
</div>
<div class='payment'>
  <input id="payments_2_:date_paid" name="payments[0][:date_paid]" type="text" />
  <br>
  <input id="payments_2_:amount_paid" name="payments[0][:amount_paid]" type="text" />
</div>
```

How can I iterate through each .payment and validate whether the first child in each is under a certain quality?

This is my attempt :

```
$.each($(".payment"), function(key, value) { 
  alert( $("value input:first").val() ); 
});
```

But the trouble I am having here is using the var `value` in getting that attribute value()

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the inputs in question are a first child, you can target them in the original selector using the [`:first-child` selector<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) , then use the native `value` property to get its value:

```
$('.payment > input:first-child').each(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

It may be worthwhile to reduce them to a set of those that do not (or do) meet validation using the [`filter()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method or the [`not()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each), use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) on the jQuery selection instead so you get access to `$(this)`:

```
$('.payment').each(function(key) {
    alert($(this).find('input:first').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$("input:first", value).val()`