# How to 'return false' within a method?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have this loop running after a click(), and it does not `return false` if the `return false` is placed deeper within the iterator. How can I ensure it returns false; ?

```
$.each($(".payment"), function(key, value) { 
  the_date = $(value).children("input:first").val();
  if( the_date != "") {
    if( the_date.split("/").length != 3) {
      return false; // <---  This doesn't work 
    };
  };
};
```

Here's another validator that does work

```
if( $("input#date_awarded").val().split("/")[2] > 2010 ) {
  return false; // <-- Totally works
};
```

Comment: Your semicolons are wrong.  Don't put semicolons after blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an `.each()`, doing `return false` returns from the each callback, and halts the loop.

Instead you could use a variable to hold the return value, and return that after the loop.

```
var returnValue = true; //use a variable for the return value
$.each($(".payment"), function (key, value) {
    the_date = $(value).children("input:first").val();
    if (the_date != "") {
        if (the_date.split("/").length != 3) {
            returnValue = false; // set the return value
            return false; // break the loop
        }
    }
});
return returnValue; // return the return value
```

Comment: `return returnValue` should be `return true`or `return undefined`

Comment: @Raynos: Are you sure? I'm pretty sure OP wants to return from an outer function with `false` if the innermost `if()` succeeds. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @patrickdw you cheated and moved the `return returnValue` statement outside the `$.each` which makes more sense. Try `return (returnValue = false)` in the `$.each` function

Comment: @Raynos: Yes, I was just about to mention that perhaps you were referring to my earlier knucklehead mistake. BTW, I reserve the right to cheat whenever it helps me look less foolish. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Taking @patrickdw code sample which fixes your bug but then cleaning your code up.

```
var returnValue = true; 
$.each($(".payment>input:first-child"), function (key, value) {
    if (this.value.split("/").length !== 3) {
        return (returnValue = false);
    }
});
return returnValue;
```

or just for kicks lets redo it in a one-line for loop without a body block.

```
for (var returnVal = true, var i = 0, var inputs = $(".payment>input:first-child"), var text = $(inputs[i]).val(); i < inputs.length && ((text.split("/").length !== 3 && (returnVal  = false)) || true); text = $(inputs[++i]).val());
return returnVal;
```

I do not recommend you torment the maintainer and write code like the above that *really really* abuses for loops.

Comment: You'd need to use `first-child` (which happened to be my answer from [OP's earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936127/children-of-many-parents-jquery-selector/4936216#4936216) ). And as long as you're cleaning things up, you might as well do `this.value` instead of using `.val()`.

Comment: @patrickdw `this.value` & `.val()` are semantically different. `.val()` does weird stuff for things and I rather not try and work out whether the substitution is safe without knowing the `type` of the `input`

Comment: Good point. They were just text inputs, so it's safe. I think the only thing `.val()` fixes for `input` elements is on `type='radio'` where there's some issue in Safari.

Comment: It's a timely utilization of pertinent details that had been hitherto undisclosed... or cheating. :o)

Answer (score 0):

return false is applied for the 'each' callback. Do you want to apply it to the 'click' callback? If so then do it like this:

```
jQuery(selector).click(function() {
    var returnValue = true;

    jQuery(anotherSelector).each(function() {
        do_stuff();
        returnValue = false;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```